# Django: How to submit a form to either create new object or get an existing one?

Tags: django, dry

Using `django1.11.4`.

I am trying to make a page for adding an item to the database, however, to do this, I need to create/get several different objects, (product, manufacturer, supplier), whose forms make up part of the whole form for adding an item.

In most case, there will be existing product, manufacturer and suppliers. So I want to retrieve the existing object and use that as the foreign key to relevant form. e.g. manufacturer is a foreign key of product.

However, for all forms when I try submitting details for the existing object. e.g supplier. The is_valid fails. The error is: `<ul class="errorlist"><li>supplier_name<ul class="errorlist"><li>Supplier with this Supplier name already exists.</li></ul></li></ul>`

Is there a way of submitting a form with 'existing data' so that I can get to pass on as a foreign key.

Thank you for your time.

```
class SupplierTestCase(FormTestCase, BasicTests):
@classmethod
def setUpTestData(cls):
    super(SupplierTestCase, cls).setUpTestData()
    cls.form = SupplierForm

def setUp(self):
    super(SupplierTestCase, self).setUp()
    self.data = {'supplier_name_text': self.supplier_name}
    self.blank_data = {
        'supplier_name_text': ['This field is required.']
    }

def test_valid_data(self):
    form = self.form(self.data)
    self.assertTrue(form.is_valid())
    commit = form.save()
    self.assertEqual(commit.supplier_name_text, self.supplier_name)

def test_get_data(self):
    form = self.form(self.data)
    self.assertTrue(form.is_valid())
    if form.is_valid():
        commit = form.save()
        self.assertEqual(commit.supplier_name_text, self.supplier_name)

    form = self.form(self.data)
    #The problem is below vvvv
    self.assertTrue(form.is_valid())
    if form.is_valid():
        commit = form.save(commit=False)
        data = model_to_dict(commit)
        get, created = Supplier.objects.get_or_create(supplier_name_text=data.get('supplier_name_text'))
        self.assertFalse(created)
```

**model**

```
class Supplier(models.Model):
    """
    The Supplier
    """
    supplier_name = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name_text
```

Comment: your model please !

Comment: @rakwen no problem give me a moment

Comment: ok i'm waiting ! . . .

Comment: my answer help you ?

Comment: Thank you @rakwen. If I remove `unique = True`, as you said I would have multiple suppliers with the same name, is it possible to keep `unique = True`, as I would end up with duplication in my db, or is removing `unique = True` the only solution?

Comment: yes many solutions exist !

Comment: first i want to know what do want to show in view ?

Comment: what do you show in your view ?

Comment: Just the form. <form> supplier: charfield, manufacturer: charfield, product_name: charfield, ... </form>. I hope it clear what I am trying to point to.

Comment: And do you accept to have many supplier with same name ?

Comment: if yes remove unique=True if not you can add autocomplete or ajax in name form field in template !

Comment: my answer is usefull ?

Answer (score 0):

```
class Supplier(models.Model):
    """
    The Supplier
    """
    name_text = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True <<<------- Take a look)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name_text
```

you have unique=True in supplied name this mean that you cannot add two supplied with same name

Comment: The OP doesn't want to have two items with the same name, that's the point of the question.